# Update a DNS to a for a dynamic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, scripting

I want to use my schools connection as a place to host a small webserver but one problem I have run into is anytime my server reboots I am given a new IP inside the schools range.

All of the schools IP are public and therefor I can access my computer directly over WAN just via the IP given in ifconfig.  I would like to be able to give my computer a dns which is easy enough when I change the Arecords to match the current IP of my computer. The problem is if my computer ever reboots (my school regularly cycles power at night and over holidays) I am assigned a new IP and have to realize it then update the Arecords

This is inconvenient and I figure there must be a better way to keep the DNS records updated either via a script or my own BIND server.  That way if there is a power cycle I can still access the server via a Domain Name.

If you have any direction to point me in it would be much appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 if that helps :).

Comment: Does this violate your AUP you signed?  If not have you considered just asking for a static address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use a dynamic DNS service such as the one offered by DynDNS, see here for more info http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/dyndns.html

Once you have an account setup, use a client like [DDClient](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient) to update your DNS records when you computer's IP changes.

Comment: DynDNS is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use your domain name and don't want to pay then you can try

http://freedns.afraid.org/ or

http://www.everydns.net --> they were bought over by DyDNS